# ¿ Cómo puedo ponerle a mi función que me de un error si hay una división de 0 en uno de los elementos de la matriz cauchy que cree?

Tags: python, python-3.x

escribo este ejercicio pidiendo alguna ayuda para poder terminar el ejercicio.

Tengo que hacer una función que me construya la matriz cauchy, los elementos de la matriz son el resultado de restar las posiciones correspondientes en elx y y vectores donde las filas corresponden a x y las columnas para y. Si hay alguna división por cero, debe generar una ValueErrorexcepción.

Mi función es la siguiente: Mi función construye la matriz pero cuando hay una división de 0 no me genera un valueError, como ponerle bien a mi función la parte del error?

```
x = np.array([45, 31, 67, 75, 54])
y = np.array([17,  7, 15, 15, 18])

def cauchy(x, y):
  x = x.reshape((-1,1))
  diff_matrix= x-y
  r = 1.0/diff_matrix
  for i, j in zip(x,y):
    if x-y=='0':
      raise ValueError("ValueError")
    else:
      return r
```

Pero acá hace la misma matriz pero no me da el error que debería darme por el elemento que hay divididio en 0.

```
x = np.array([45, 31, 67, 75, 54])
y = np.array([17,  7, 15, 75, 18])
cauchy(x,y)
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: no lo compares con un string `'0'` comparalo con un entero `0`, `if x-y==0`

Comment: Además puedes usar un `try/except` para capturar la excepción ya que por defecto python la detecta y para la ejecución del programa si no es manejada

Comment: Y la comparación con 0 debes hacerla antes de intentar la división, de lo contrario se te producirá la excepción `ZeroDivisionError` antes de darte oportunidad de generar la tuya.

Comment: ```def cauchy(x, y):
  for i, j in zip(x,y):
    try:
      if x-y==0:
        print(r)
    except:
      print("ValueError")
      x = x.reshape((-1,1))
      diff_matrix= x-y
      r = 1.0/diff_matrix
      return r```                                                                                                           Lo hice así, pero esta función me sigue creando la matriz pero no me lanza el error cuando hay dicha división solo lo pone como inf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que esta intentando manejar el error después de que sucede y como ya el han dicho esta comparando elementos de tipo `int` `x` y `y` con `str` (0) en el `if x-y=='0'` además de que esta comparando directamente la resta de dos matrices con un solo valor lo cual es incorrecto debe usar los valores de la iteración `i` y `j`

```
x = np.array([45, 31, 67, 75, 54])
y = np.array([17,  7, 15, 15, 18])

def cauchy(x, y):
    x = x.reshape((-1,1))
    diff_matrix= x-y
    for i, j in zip(x,y):
        if i-j==0:
            raise ValueError("Esta intentando dividir entre 0")
    r = 1.0/diff_matrix
    return r
```

Comment: ah sí, es que estaba poniendo toda la parte de la diferencia abajo y solo era r el resto si debía dejarla ahí arriba. Y el raise sí era. Le agradezco por orientarme en cómo organizar mi función.